# How row Span added to material table Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-table

I'm trying to add rowSpan to my table. Please refer below attached sample table and my data set .I need table like that. Can anyone help me to do this?

[image]

[image]

```
                                      <ng-container matColumnDef="month">
                                          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="text-left"> Month </th>
                                          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ row.date.yearRef.year }} </td>
                                      </ng-container>

                                      <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
                                          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="text-left"> Type </th>
                                          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ row.budgets[0].type }} </td>
                                      </ng-container>

                                      <ng-container matColumnDef="revenue">
                                          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="text-left"> Revenue </th>
                                          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ row.budgets[0].revenue }} </td>
                                      </ng-container>

                                      <ng-container matColumnDef="gp">
                                          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="text-left"> GP </th>
                                          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ row.budgets[0].gp }} </td>
                                      </ng-container>

                                      <ng-container matColumnDef="pbt">
                                          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="text-left"> Profit Before Tax </th>
                                          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ row.budgets[0].profitBeforeTax }} </td>
                                      </ng-container>

                                      <ng-container matColumnDef="pat">
                                          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="text-left"> Profit After Tax </th>
                                          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{ row.budgets[0].profitAfterTax }} </td>
                                      </ng-container>

                                      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="FinancedisplayedColumns"></tr>
                                      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: FinancedisplayedColumns"></tr>
                                  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution, Please refer the attached link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lnahlh?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,app%2Ftable-basic-example.css

Comment: good work! Feel free to add to your answer not only the link, but also the relevant part of your code. (this helps other users even if your link will be lost in future)

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks. I'll add my code also.